# Permission denied when deleting file created successfully by fopen

Tags: c++, file

This is a function that takes a folder name from the user,creates a text file and should delete it later on.

```
void function(string LogFolder)
{
     fopen((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str(),"w");
     cout<<"The errorno of fopen "<<errno<<endl;
     remove((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str());
     cout<<"The errorno of remove "<<errno<<endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
The errorno of fopen    0[Means that file was successfully created.]
The errorno of remove  13[Means that Permission denied]

As you can see the folder has **not** been deleted successfully.
[A link to understand error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx)

Comment: You should `fclose()` before trying to remove the folder.

Comment: Don't check `errno` unless you actually *know* the previous function failed. The value of `errno` is *unspecified* if a function doesn't fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the file first:

```
void function(string LogFolder)
{
     // Acquire file handle
     FILE* fp = fopen((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str(),"w");

     if(fp == NULL) // check if file creation failed
     {
          cout<<"The errorno of fopen "<<errno<<endl;
          return;
     }

     // close opened file
     if(fclose(fp) != 0)
     {
         cout<<"The errorno of fclose "<<errno<<endl;
     }


     if(remove((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str()) != 0)
     {
          cout<<"The errorno of remove "<<errno<<endl;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for starters, you are not creating and deleting a folder, but a file named `test.txt` inside the folder.

Your problem is that you need to close the file before you will be allowed to delete it.  Try the following

```
void function(string LogFolder)
{
    FILE* myFile = fopen((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str(),"w");
    cout<<"The errorno of fopen "<<errno<<endl;
    fclose( myFile );
    cout<<"The errorno of fclose "<<errno<<endl;
    remove((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str());
    cout<<"The errorno of remove "<<errno<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set execution permissions on the folder as well as write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This is the because the file is still open. You should `fclose()` it before removing the folder.
Something like

```
void function(string LogFolder)
{
     FILE *fp = fopen((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str(),"w");
     cout<<"The errorno of fopen "<<errno<<endl;
     fclose(fp);
     remove((LogFolder+"/test.txt").c_str());
     cout<<"The errorno of remove "<<errno<<endl;
}
```